# Overall code structure fail

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I'm starting with HTML and CSS and i have written my first page for my friend. Problem is that my code seems to be pretty bad, cause when i try to change few things, whole page almost crashes.

map of my page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U1lO.png

So here's the thing:

1. Logo + navigation menu

here's code:

```css
#logo {
 margin-left: 15%; }

nav {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-top: 1%;
 font-weight: bold;
 vertical-align: central; }

a {
 text-decoration: none; }

nav ul {
 list-style-type: none; }

nav li {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;

}
```

1. Slider is only thing made well i think, cause i made it margin-left and right on: auto;
2. Here starts the fun:

code of news:

```css
 .newsy {
 font-weight: 900;
 font-size: xx-large;
 margin-left: 15%;
 color: black; }


.image-box {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 15%;
 width: 640px;
 height: 300px; }

 .image-box span {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
     color: white;
     padding: 15px;
 }


.community-box {
 margin-right: 15% ;
 float: right;
 }

.baner-box {
 float: right;
 width: 270px;
 height: 500px;
 margin-right: 15%; }

 .baner-box baner {
     margin: 40px;
 }

 .autor {
 border: solid 0px white;
 background-color: white;
 margin-left: 15%;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 width: 610px;
 background-color: white;
 position: relative;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-kerning: normal; }

 .readmore {
 position:absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 90px;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .9);
 color: white;

 }
```

When i try to move them from center to a bit of left whole page is crashing. 
Also my community boxes (facebook, YT and twitter) aren't too properly set.

Can anybody help me and say what mistakes I have made ? It's really important.
Greets.

P.S. tell me if you need whole code i can upload package of it.

Comment: What do you mean by "page is crashing"?

Comment: If you are new to this, maybe it would help to use a framework for your first project. You could take a look at ZURB: http://foundation.zurb.com/templates.php

Comment: I mean that few elements lose their properties, change their position etc..

Comment: You should make two fiddles. One with your original code, and one with the change you are trying to make, that messes it all up.

Comment: You should post HTML+CSS.
Share it using codepen.io or jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://cdpn.io/yGmBA

Here is my html + css codtes, I will appreciate if you could tell me how bad my code is. One of the issues appear when i want to add new newses them my page doesn't look too good. Mostly i mean these last 2 news. 
Another problem is that my page doesn't look too well on bigger resolutions. If you might check it out on ur screens, you will understand, any advice how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

this may be happen because the width and height's pixel is may be greater than your display's pixel so i suggest you to give it in %
like
    .baner-box {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-right: 15%; }

may be work for you